# C++: Optimizing a simple image clipping operation... too many if() statements

Tags: c++, image, clipping

The code I have here is preliminary. I am focusing on the clipping procedures. There seems to be a lot of if() statements, and I'm hoping someone will have a clever way of optimizing this at least a little bit.

If you're wondering what m_nStride is, it's the number of elements to add to any given pixel pointer to reach the pixel directly below it (y + 1, x + 0). But either way, that is unimportant pertaining to my question.

The general idea is to fill a rectangular area of the image (32-bpp) using coordinates left, top, width and height. In cases where the coordinates would cause that area to cross the boundaries of the image, the area would be clipped to fit inside the image instead of being interpreted as an error.

```
void Image::Clear(int nLeft, int nTop, int nWidth, int nHeight, DWORD dwColor)
{
    if(nWidth <= 0) return;
    if(nHeight <= 0) return;
    if(nLeft >= m_nWidth) return;
    if(nTop >= m_nHeight) return;

    if(nLeft < 0)
    {
        nWidth += nLeft;
        if(nWidth <= 0)
            return;
        nLeft = 0;
    }

    if(nTop < 0)
    {
        nHeight += nTop;
        if(nHeight <= 0)
            return;
        nTop = 0;
    }

    if(nLeft + nWidth > m_nWidth)
    {
        nWidth -= ((nLeft + nWidth) - m_nWidth);
        if(nWidth <= 0) 
            return;
    }

    if(nTop + nHeight > m_nHeight)
    {
        nHeight -= ((nTop + nHeight) - m_nHeight);
        if(nHeight <= 0)
            return;
    }

    DWORD *p = m_pBuffer + (m_nStride * nTop) + nLeft;
    for(int y = 0; y < nHeight; y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < nWidth; x++)
            p[x] = dwColor;
        p += m_nStride;
    }
}
```

Comment: Optimize to what goal? Performance? Lines of code? Clarity? Generality?

Comment: Performance... maybe a cleverer way of testing all the possibilities without using so many if() statements, as most of the time the area will not need to be clipped, so it's just wasted code... but I'm too safe-minded to not have the clipping code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For performance, the `if` overhead is virtually zero compared to the `for` loops. Nonetheless, as an exercise here's a version with fewer checks. It clips the bounds first and then only needs to check width and height being positive.

```
void Image::Clear(int nLeft, int nTop, int nWidth, int nHeight, DWORD dwColor)
{
    if(nLeft < 0)
    {
        nWidth += nLeft;
        nLeft = 0;
    }

    if(nTop < 0)
    {
        nHeight += nTop;
        nTop = 0;
    }

    if(nLeft + nWidth > m_nWidth)
    {
        nWidth = m_nWidth - nLeft;
    }

    if(nTop + nHeight > m_nHeight)
    {
        nHeight = m_nHeight - nTop;
    }

    if(nWidth <= 0) return;
    if(nHeight <= 0) return;

    DWORD *p = m_pBuffer + (m_nStride * nTop) + nLeft;
    for(int y = 0; y < nHeight; y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < nWidth; x++)
            p[x] = dwColor;
        p += m_nStride;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks... I will try that out... As far as the for() loops are concerned, the compiler optimizes them pretty well. I have tried all manner of storing algorithms and so-called "optimized" assembly code structures that weren't even as fast as MSDEV2010 optimized code when given the base+index of the buffer in the for loop

Comment: I would vote you up but apparently I cannot do that yet... sorry... I will return some day and vote you up